# Real-time updates?

Tags: feature-request

I know this is a bit of a stretch, as it probably requires something on StackExchange's part or whatever, I don't know. But I find myself refreshing constantly, and in an age of Javascript and HTML5, it's suddenly irritating to have to navigate pages and check for updates. So many things could be JS Pop-ups or realtime updates...or am I just crazy?

Comment: I agree real-time updates would be nice, but it'd also have to be done in a way such that content doesn't just start moving all over the place while you are trying to, say, click a link.

Comment: True. I wasn't thinking about main browsing. Hmm.

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the homepage, then you can install [Live Home Page](https://stackapps.com/questions/2684/live-home-page-never-touch-the-refresh-button-on-the-home-page-of-a-stack-exch), a small UserScript that updates the homepage with questions as they are asked without needing to refresh the page (**disclaimer:** I wrote it).

If on the other hand you are referring to a desktop application or browser extension that lets you know when people answer your questions, comment to you, etc. then you need to head on over to [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) where you can find a number of programs / extensions that do that.

I have written a couple you might be interested in:

- [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-version-1-5) - a cross-platform (Windows and Linux) desktop application that sits in your system tray / status panel and pops up little notifications when an event occurs on one of your accounts.
- Stack Alert ([Chrome](https://stackapps.com/questions/2874/stack-alert-google-chrome-extension-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing), [Firefox](https://stackapps.com/questions/2909/stack-alert-mozilla-firefox-add-on-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing-t), [Opera](https://stackapps.com/questions/2948/stack-alert-opera-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing-to-have-a-stack-ex)) - a browser extension that displays the number of unread items in your Stack Exchange inbox and makes it easy to view them with the click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? On the question page itself, or elsewhere? What specifically is the problem?

Please search http://meta.stackoverflow.com as I believe this kind of request has been made before, and you might be able to vote for it there to move it up in the priority list.